# Researching on Animate() in Jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Inside a Main Wrapper , I have 5 Divs. The very First div contains 4 Box(box_1, box_2,box_3,box_4) where my click event will occur.

Other 4 divs inside main wrapper , are the content of box_1, box_2, box_3, box_4 respectivly.
All box contain an hyperlink tag with unique Id to Move back to very first div.

For first time, When I click on any menu , corressponding box container appers.

e.g, clicked on redbox > Moved to Box-1 content > Clicked on Back to menu > Moved to 4 Colored box section.

Again clicked on gany box. Lets say , Green box> Moved to Box2 container > Clicked on Back to Menu > Oops !!! My 4 Colored box jut slide out from my screen.

Here is the JS Fiddle lINK. I want the 4 colored div section to stay on the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnaranjita_nayak/8XcZX/

## HTML ##

```
<div class="main_wrapper" id="main_wrapper">
    <div class="container_fluid" id="menu">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box1" id="box_1"></div>
                <div class="box2" id="box_2"></div> <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

             <div class="row">
                <div class="box3" id="box_3"></div>
                <div class="box4" id="box_4"></div> <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div><!---End of Container fluid--->

     <div class="container_fluid" id="box_1_sec" style="display:none;margin-right:-170px;">
         <h1>Box1 Content</h1>
         <a href="#" id="back1">Back to #Menu</a>
    </div>
         <div class="container_fluid" id="box_2_sec" style="display:none;margin-right:-170px;">
         <h1>Box2 Content</h1>
          <a href="#" id="back2">Back to #Menu</a>
    </div>
     <div class="container_fluid" id="box_3_sec" style="display:none;margin-right:-170px;">
         <h1>Box3 Content</h1>
          <a href="#" id="back3">Back to #Menu</a>
    </div>
     <div class="container_fluid" id="box_4_sec" style="display:none;margin-right:-170px;">
         <h1>Box4 Content</h1>
         <a href="#" id="back4">Back to #Menu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.container_fluid {
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width:1208px;
    margin:auto;
}
.row {
    padding:3% 3% 3% 3%;
}
.box1 {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
}
.box2 {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.box3 {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
}
.box4 {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:brown;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
}
```

### JS

```
$("#box_1,#box_2,#box_3,#box_4").click(function(){
    var clicked_id=$(this).attr('id');
    var menu=$('#menu');
    menu.animate({
            "marginLeft":"-=150%"
        },
         {
            duration: 500,
            step: function() {
                //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
                console.log($(this).width());
            },
            complete: function() {
                 // console.log("finished");
                 menu.hide();
                       $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").show();
                         $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").animate({
                            "marginRight":"+=170%"
                         },
                         {
                            duration: 500,
                            step: function() {
                                //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
                                console.log($(this).width());
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                 console.log("finished");
                            }
                         });

            }
         });
    $("#back1,#back2,#back3,#back4").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
         $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").animate({
            "marginRight":"-=170%"
         },
          {
            duration: 500,
            step: function() {
                console.log($(this).width());
            },
            complete: function() {

                 $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").hide()
                        menu.show();
                          menu.animate({
                            "marginLeft":"+=150%"
                         },
                         {
                            duration: 500,
                            step: function() {

                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                 console.log("finished");
                            }
                         });
            }
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 "marginRight":"+=170%"
```

every time you add 170% or :

```
"marginLeft":"-=150%"
```

decrease 150% , this should be set , not increment or decrement the value.

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/8XcZX/1/

```
$("#box_1,#box_2,#box_3,#box_4").click(function(){
    var clicked_id=$(this).attr('id');
    var menu=$('#menu');
    menu.animate({
            "marginLeft":"-=150%"
        },
         {
            duration: 500,
            step: function() {
                //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
                console.log($(this).width());
            },
            complete: function() {
                 // console.log("finished");
                 menu.hide();
                       $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").show();
                         $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").animate({
                            "marginRight":"+=170%"
                         },
                         {
                            duration: 500,
                            step: function() {
                                //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
                                console.log($(this).width());
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                 console.log("finished");
                            }
                         });

            }
         });
    $("#back1,#back2,#back3,#back4").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
         $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").animate({
            "marginRight":"-=170%"
         },
          {
            duration: 500,
            step: function() {
                console.log($(this).width());
            },
            complete: function() {

                 $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec").hide()
                        menu.show();
                          menu.animate({
                            "marginLeft":"0%"
                         },
                         {
                            duration: 500,
                            step: function() {

                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                 console.log("finished");
                            }
                         });
            }
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx ProllyGeek :)))) It works!!! :) But When I am performing the same task for several times, e.g clicking on Menu , cuming back to container, then clicking the hyperlink ,,,If I perform the same task repeatedly , It seems like My animation Efeect is getting delayed. My Animation effect should respond as soon as I click my box. Any Help on that?

Comment: Animation Effect getting delayed after several clicks on Divs. Any One help on the issue. My Animation speed should be 500.

Comment: @Swapna please hold on im checking your code once more.

Comment: @Swapna you are getting more than 1 alert everytime you press back right , cause your code is building a stack of function calls.

Comment: Hmm, Thats Right , Any Other way you can mention , to perform the same task?

Comment: @Swapna yes your code is fine once you dont use links , you cant bind click listener to a link this way or this is what you get.

Comment: You are Simply Awesome :) Thanx a lot. Looking forward to add some more functionality :)

Comment: But I think , My container box is not animating as you set margin-left:0. It sd animate...@ProllyGeek

Comment: Not a Problem , We can animate that :)

Comment: a little more twist. Now I have added a div out of main wrapper named Meta. Clicking on it , will bring the meta_sec div to the screen with animation. The current code for meta in js section only successfuly executed when I am in box_container_sec. i.e. Click on any box> Move to corressponding box> then click on meta. The meta  link doesnot work , when I am on my 4 colored box menu section. Can you help me out ? It should work when I am on my 4 colored div section tooo.

Comment: @Swapna is this the code with the issue ? i cant see any metas !

Comment: what is the prob exactly ?

Comment: Prblem is While I am on My  Home Page, Clicking on Meta link, doesnot slide out Home page. (As I have only added "#"+clicked_id+'_sec') , so It is only working when I am in inner pages. I want Meta link should work on hOME PAGE also.

Comment: and after it slides out what should happen ?

Comment: Home Page Should Slide Right, AND meta_sec content sd slide in. Like, Clicking on red colored box , brings box_1 container. The same is not happening with meta section , while I am on Home page.

Comment: Hmm Nyc, It works for Home Page Now. bUT c, iF i CLICK ON RED COLORED BOX> Moved to corressponding container > Then Click on Meta> Oops , Though Meta section apperas, It dint silde out corressponding container of red box. It jus appears below of it. I want the While we are in Inner pages e.g Box_1_section, clicking on Meta link , should slide out box_1_container , bring back Meta_sec like the effect you jus show on Home page.

Comment: You are Really a Pro Geek.:))) May I animate $("#"+clicked_id+"_sec") this thing rather than hiding??

Comment: it is my bed time i wanna really help you but have to sleep right now , i promise i will answer this once im up as im posting this from stackoverflow android app ,right from bed :)

Comment: Ohk :) Thnx for helping me out :) Gd N8 :)

Comment: @Swapna so how can i help ?

Comment: Hey , Hi , I just solved all riddles on my way :) Thanx for all valuable help on my way :)